# How can I add the CastCompanionLibrary as a dependency to my Android Studio module?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Anyone know how to add the CastCompanionLibrary to an Android Studio module? Basically I have a module called C, it is on this path /A/B/C where B is the project the module belongs to. I did a git clone of the CCL inside /A so basically I have this path /A/CastCompanionLibrary-android and now I want to have project C use the CCL.

How can I do that with gradle on Android Studio?

Thanks.

EDIT: I think I just figured it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/26892582/704836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just figured it out.

On the Android Studio project, under settings.gradle add this:

```
include ':CastCompanionLibrary-android'
project(':CastCompanionLibrary-android').projectDir = new File( '/Users/myuser/workspace/android/CastCompanionLibrary-android')
```

On the build.gradle where I want to use it as a dependency:

```
compile project(':CastCompanionLibrary-android')
```

Comment: This worked for me, too. Thanks!  However the project name is now just "CastCompanionLibrary"